# Can I play on a < 1.8 SMP version of Minecraft with the 1.8 without breaking something?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have the 1.8 pre-release version and I'm wondering if I go on a server that is not yet upgraded, will it break something or will I crash ?

Does higher version compatible with older version ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You cannot play on a server if your client version does not match the server version*.**  Different versions are not compatible with each other.

I run a server that me and some friends play on. If someone tries to connect with the wrong version, the server will say that it's disconnecting them because they have a different version, and the client will simply give one of the many errors we all have come to know.

While I haven't tested the 1.8 pre-release *specifically*, my experience with former versions says that it will not break anything, it just won't work.

*To an extent, anyway.  1.7.2 works with 1.7.3, but larger gaps (e.g. 1.6 and 1.7) will not work.

Comment: Side note: [How to keep 2 different versions installed without them conflicting](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/how-do-i-keep-two-different-versions-of-minecraft-installed/30123#30123).