# How do I fix my vintage world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My favorite single-player map is relatively old - created no later than beta 1.1.  Since then, the terrain generation algorithms have changed.  When I explore any farther, I'm faced with glitches like sliced mountains and differences in sea level.

I tried making a new world with the same seed, but it turned out completely different.

Is there a way to smooth the transition between the old and new automatically, or will I have to run around terraforming myself?

Comment: There's no tool I know of to do this automatically. [VoxelSniper](http://www.voxelwiki.com/minecraft/VoxelSniper) is a large-scale in-game terrain editor that would make the terraforming easier, but you'd have to set up a local Bukkit server, install the VoxelSniper plugin, add (a copy!) of your world, connect to the server to change things, and then copy the world files back to your single-player worlds directory.

Comment: I don't know enough about it to post it as a full on answer, but I believe MCEdit allows you to transplant chunks from one map to another. If nothing else, it'll let you pick and choose which chunks to bring forward (like chunks with structures).

Comment: You may not be able to fix the problem, but one fun option would be to pack up all your belongings and take a long, long, ***long*** trip through the Nether until you reach an area far beyond the borders of your already-explored regions. This will give the terrain generator a nice blank canvas while keeping your legacy world around too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The world generation has radically changed since 1.8 (and will change again in 1.9+), so it's most likely not possible to directly run your world again. In my tests, a world imported from 1.7.3 into 1.8 did have significant changes in the biomes and the landscape.

A workaround which would always work, if you're ready to relinquish new features, would be to keep the binaries (~/.minecraft/bin) of the old version around and swap them around as needed.

Comment: [How to keep 2 different versions of MineCraft installed.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/how-do-i-keep-two-different-versions-of-minecraft-installed/30123#30123)