# Is there a standalone free offline version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried searching the website and couldnt find a question that answered this specific aspect of the game. Its very difficult for me to use the internet because of my location, and I have recently become interested in Minecraft.

Im aware that there is a pay version that can be played offline once youve logged in once but the idea of doing anything internet related that requires almost any kind of talking between my computer and the internet is laughable where I am right now.

Even just downloading it will probably take a day or more. Also with a connection like the one I have I sure as heck dont want to pay to play.

Is there a way I can download the game, for free, and play OFFLINE, for free?

Comment: If there was a downloadable version that required no internet connection after downloading it, would you pay for it?  Why would the internet-connected version of minecraft cost money but the connection-free version be free?

Comment: I appreciate the attempts but I just got three extremely different answers, back to back. Thats not very helpfull. LoL

Comment: Let me rephrase what @Dave asked: You want for _free_ what everyone else _pays_ for?

Comment: there is an outdated [demo](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/04/19/download-the-minecraft-demo/) which allows you to play the full game, the only limitation is that worlds become un-modifiable after 90 min.  (also, the correct answer is [lunbooks'](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44406/88) one, maybe my comment there helps you though)

Comment: negative, I dont want for free what everyone pays for. I want, for free, whats free. I was simply asking if a free and entirely offline version of the game excists. One that doesnt require a one-time login or anything like that. I dont see what the big deal is.

Comment: @Ender then you mean either the demo or the very old [minecraft classic](http://www.minecraft.net/classic/play). Most of us understood you wanted the full new game, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Ender if you need help with the download, let me know.  I can get media sent to you.

Comment: If you can get on this website, you should be able to log in once with no problem.  It's the download that's the tricky part with your crappy connection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since we clarified you're not looking for a pirated version :-) There are three choices:

- [Minecraft Classic](http://www.minecraft.net/classic/play), which is <strike>very old</strike> no longer available, lacks e.g. redstone and zombies, but is still great if you like simply to sandbox.
- The [Demo](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/04/19/download-the-minecraft-demo/), which is not up-to-date but features redstone and is in survival mode (health bar, swords, spiders...). Any world you create there can however only be modified for 90 minutes
- The full version (you have to buy it in this case), have it downloaded by someone else and have them snail-mail you the whole folder `%appdata%\.minecraft\`.

**edit** As [John](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/16398/john) commented, the internet-heavy part is the download, so for the third solution you can ask said person use their login, send you their .minecraft (excluding the file `lastlogin` to keep it legal, and the `saves` folder isn't necessary either) and then connect to the internet once to login with your own account. If there has been an update meanwhile, you can choose "update later". After the first login, it will work without internet connection

To avoid snail mailing, your friend can also upload the folder to something like dropbox and you can use a download manager. It's only about 50 MB after all.

Or if you do not want to use the Internet to log in, you can use the following command (that goes in your run box) to start Minecraft without logging in (assuming you have the `.minecraft` files in `%APPDATA%`

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft` yourusername
```

Comment: I thought people who ordered after Alpha no longer receive all future updates for free

Comment: how would i use your third choice, pay for it, and give a friend my login information to download it?

Comment: @Ender either that or ask him to use his login, since after buying it for yourself too, morally that's ok as well I guess. But John is right, if your connection is good enough to visit this site, it is sufficient to have your friend download it, get the .minecraft folder and then login with your own account since all downloads have then already taken place - unless there is an update

Comment: @NickT are you sure about this? I bought beta and still get updates, and what kind of strategy would it be to deny after-release customers their update? I think the only difference is that you no longer get the 25% discount

Comment: What I heard is that Mojang, on advice from their lawyers, rescinded their _promise_ to provide all future updates for free after Alpha. That doesn't mean they can't still choose to provide free updates, or that they're particularly likely to charge for them - just that customers from after Alpha aren't entitled to them (e.g. to sue if they decide to charge for updates / a sequel / optional DLC).

Comment: @Random832 ok, thanks for that information. I doubt Notch considers this more than a litigation-armor though :-7

Comment: @Ender I updated the third solution a bit, making sure you and your friend don't accidentally cross legal lines. (I'm not sure Notch approves of sending the game data around, but under the given circumstances I guess he'd understand)

Comment: @Random832 Somewhere I read (I think it was Notch's blog) that rescinding future updates meant that if he ever made something like Minecraft 2, he isn't obliged to give it for free.

Comment: @John, thanks guys, your help has really been paramount. If logging in is as traffic light as visiting this site then I should be ok. Im used to games like Starcraft2\WoW\LoL where just 'logging in' is a traffic heavy action. Downloading it wont be a problem, Ill just set it up for overnight.  Guess I'm shellin out 20 bucks. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: If you dont want to log in, just place the .minecraft in your %appdata% and do `java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
` in your run box (WinKey + R, for Vista and 7)

Comment: ok so ive downloaded the exe file but that was super small. 263k to be exact... and now I keep timing out if I try to update, or get a black screen if I opt to 'not update'. Im assuming the first update is mandatory and THATS the 50mbs you were talking about?

Comment: @Ender precisely, and the problem is I don't know of a direct download for which you can use a download managerand that's where a friend comes into play putting his .minecraft folder online for you. but minecraft.net seems to have trouble at the moment anyway, so it may also work better after xmas holidays. tip: once you get minecraft running and feel like trying to update, backup .minecraft first

Comment: @Ender I haven't tried it myself, but [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30123/88) may be helpful for you

Comment: Several tries and more than a few hours later its finished and runs fine! I actually had to scour the internet because this version doesnt give you the sound files in the resource folder, I had to find and download those seperatly, jeez that was a headache. Tobias, your awesome.

Comment: @Ender great to see it helps, enjoy your minecraft then :-)

Answer (score 10):

No, there is not.

However, as you pointed out, the paid version can be played offline indefinitely after you've downloaded it. I'm not sure what difference a free version would make in that regard, as you'd still have to download it.

Comment: @Ender just a side note, to play the full version offline, you have to login _once_. You can do this on another computer with internet though, and then copy `%appdata%\.minecraft` to your other PC and there you can play offline without ever having your PC connected to the internet

Comment: Appreciate the idea, it would work in a normal situation, but im currently on a mountain in a third world country. i cant just go to a friends pc, his internet is gonna suck as much as mine is.

Comment: @Ender but you _have_ to download it at least once. If you use a download manager you won't have to download the whole game at once but can continue after an interrupted connection. Another choice would be having `.minecraft/` and the `Minecraft.exe` downloaded by someone else and put on a CD or USB flash drive and sent to you via snail mail.

Comment: @Zommuter - of course, downloading a Download manager is probably gonna have the same problem ;)

Comment: @Robotnik True, but usually download managers specifically have a "download the download manager" tool which is really small in size. If one used linux, there'd most likely be `wget` in the basic installation at least. Windows though...

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is, and its called Minecraft Classic. You can find a download link to it currently on the main [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net) website on the right hand side. It is a very out dated version of the game however and is pretty much akin to the Creative mode that minecraft has now.

Comment: it seemed to me that playing classic required the browser, am i mistaken?

Comment: It is a Java Application like any other.. In the browser is a way to load a jar file, but you can download it and play it as you like. There is no online required component to it that I am aware of.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is, actually.  http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/04/19/download-the-minecraft-demo it lets you play on the world for ninety minutes until it locks and doesn't let you play the world. You can have as many worlds as you want. It is outdated though.

There is another way, but... It's stealing and most likely illegal.

Comment: Strictly speaking that is a free version of Minecraft, but, well, it's a demo. Also very much outdated.

Comment: @lunboks Thanks, I didn'tt know that. I edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there isn't. The game is amazing, and I suggest you pay for it. The old version is free, yes, but there is no way to download it (though you might be able to download the jar, but I don't know if it will run without an internet connection).

Answer (score -2):

Play the the online demo, then open minecraft, click login then play offline