# Why can't I connect to a minecraft LAN server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

My sister and I are trying to run a Minecraft server for us to play on together.

We live in the same house, using the same internet connection and our computers are near each other but we are using different user names. When I try to connect I get the following error:

```
**Failed to connect to the server** Connection timed out: connect
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I assume this is the case, but just to clarify, the server is also located on your LAN?  Also, welcome to Arqade!

Comment: to be honest, i tried making a server, but it wouldnt show up on her lan games... we tried to direct connect, as in i told her the IP of what it was hosted on, it said "Local game hosted on 192.168.1.x:xxxxx" with 'x' being the rest of it, and i just tried to open my ipconfig.exe, but as i open it, it closes a split second later. but what do you mean 'the server is also located on your LAN?' ?

Comment: Voting to close as a dup; but +1 for good description that helps rule out common mistakes