# My friend can't join my LAN server and I can't join his

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

My mate and I have updated our Minecraft and it's fine, but we are trying to join each other's games via LAN. It just says `connecting` and then times out. We have different accounts and live close to each other - can somebody tell me whats up? We have migrated our accounts on mojang as somebody on a video said to do that. Can somebody help us please?

Comment: `live close to each other` - a LAN is a single network, living close is not enough.

Comment: ok thanks we know that now so its better just to make a server then

Comment: Yes, you'll want to make a server.

Comment: Don't forget to [forward the correct ports](http://superuser.com/questions/280660/allowing-a-friend-to-connect-over-the-internet-to-a-minecraft-server-ive-hosted).

Comment: I use [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/Hamachi/download.aspx) to play with my friends. It has made my server admin life so much easier :D

Comment: @Adanion You should make that a full answer.

Comment: I've found [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/) to be both easier to set up and more reliable than Hamachi

Comment: Is this a new trend, useful posts stuffed into comments and no answer?

Answer (score 1):

A LAN Game is a server in the same network, if you aren't in the same network, then it won't work. It will only work if you two are in the same house with the same network. Also, I don't think you need to port forward since you two are already in the same connection so you don't need to worry about that as well. Just make sure you two are in the same general area and with the same connection.

Comment: You may have to disable or allow traffic from a specific port if you have a firewall of some sort (the windows default one, or any anti-virus software). The port number is usualy 25565.

Comment: Well probably, to be honest i got this from googling for about 5 seconds, these people do no research before posting their questions... I haven't played Minecraft for about 2 months already, (I have like 1 gig of ram left on my Laptop) so I have no idea what's in this new update.