# My brother and I are unable to connect to minecraft LAN servers, any way we can fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

When we click 'Open To LAN'  it gives us an ip address but  when we use that to Direct Connect it doesn't work. We've also let the "Searching for LAN worlds" sit there for an hour and nothing happened.

I'm not the best with computers but I do know a decent amount of stuff.  Our internet is also NOT the best(ping, upload speeds, etc.) Is there anything we can do to fix it?  Btw for moderators and such, I'm only posting a new questions since I: Couldn't comment on other question, and I tried many things that other people answered on similar questions.

Comment: Hey, Tyler.  We've closed your question because it's a duplicate of the linked question.  Just because you can't post a comment doesn't mean you should open a new question; that just leads it to be closed like it did.

Comment: @Tyler hey, welcome to ArQAde! In the future please suggest an edit into the original question so that it will cover your issue as well as the one it already covered, rather than opening a duplicate.

Comment: +1 despite being a dup, because I'd rather see you get enough rep to comment when its appropriate ;)