# Cannot connect to local Craftbukkit server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

So my issue is this, I've installed Craftbukkit and its running, but I can't connect. I've tried:

- Adding my own IP to the server's info, which doesn't work
- Leave it blank and try to connect through game putting in local host, it says 'Lost connection.'

Ive read all over the internet and no answer has ever worked for me, I've even turned off my firewall and it still did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: @JoethePerson - Sounds more like he's running the server locally i.e. on the same machine as the client. I'd say it's a different issue

Comment: Dare i ask if your server is running on a different port? Other than minecraft's default 25565

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a default configuration you should be able to connect using the address `localhost`.

If you specify your computer's address in the configuration (i.e. `server-ip=<something>`) and cannot connect with that same address, you may need to open up port 25565 in your firewall software. However, you should get a `Connection refused` message if that is the case.

If you have tried either of the above two solutions and continue getting `Connection lost` I suggest you temporarily disable any anti-virus software that may be running on your system and give it another try.