# How do I add Minecraft as a firewall exception?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cannot play LAN on Minecraft as the game I am trying to join does not appear on the list.

The other person can see my game, but is unable to join as they receive a timed out error.

If I turn the firewall off, it works fine. In the firewall, when Minecraft is set to either public or private, it does not work.

When the person I want to play with (or he wants to play with me), I cannot visibly see any LAN games on my multi-player screen. The other person can see my lan game that I try hosting, but when he clicks on it, it sits on the connecting to server screen for several minutes before a connection timed out error occurs on his computer. How can I make it so that we can play together, but I don't have to shut down the firewall?

Comment: So it works fine with your firewall off? It sounds like you just need to look up how to add an exception to your firewall for Minecraft.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: This question basically boils down to "how do I add Minecraft as a firewall exception?" now.

Comment: Which is either a duplicate or a valid question that needs to be asked and answered.

Comment: Add the current `javaw.exe` binary to the exception list.

Comment: @DarkWolffe Any reason why that's a comment instead of posted as an answer that can be voted on and accepted?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie when I added that comment, the thread was still locked.

Comment: you can use [tunneling technique](http://tunnelin.com/blog/how-to-allow-minecraft-through-firewall) for exposing Minecraft server - it does not require Firewall or router configuration and much easier to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is a firewall issue, which it very much sounds like the case is, then you need to add your current running Java binary to the firewall. By default, it is the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe
```

Or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe
```

The first pathway assumes you're on a 32-bit system, or that you're on a 64-bit system with a 64-bit install of Java. The second pathway is for 64-bit systems running 32-bit installs. Both pathways assume that you have the latest version of Java (as of this post) which is Java 1.8 update 31.

You can add this exception to the firewall by typing into the Windows Start search area "Allow Firewall" and clicking the "Allow an App through Windows Firewall" result, then clicking the "Change Settings" button at the top, clicking the "Allow Another App..." button at the bottom, and browsing for the binary in the above pathways. Click "Add", "OK" and you should be set.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use a different binary through your Minecraft launcher, do the same process but to the other executable.

Comment: My firewall already has exception for `javaw.exe` in minecraft folder (but it does not help). Do you think it is safe to add file that you mentioned in your post. Everything with java now will go through. I am much more comfortable to add individual applications exceptions.