# How to join peoples minecraft world using lan

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get someone into your minecraft world on lan

Comment: Are the people you want to join you on the same network? What happens when you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're on the same [local area network (LAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network), it should be as simple as clicking the "Open to LAN" button while in the world you wish for them to join.

[image]