# Minecraft lan server not working 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

**Potential fix:**

1. Open Minecraft 1.8.9
2. Click Multiplayer
3. Wait until it finds the lan server and note the IP it says
4. Close Minecraft 1.8.9 and open Minecraft 1.9
5. Click Multiplayer
6. Click Direct Connect
7. Enter the IP you have just written down and click Join Server

---

When my brother opened a LAN world, my other brother could simply join using Windows 10. On my Mac I can't. Reversed, if I set up a LAN, my brothers can actually join my world normally. what am I doing wrong?

By 'LAN world' I mean a Singleplayer game that they share via the `Open to LAN` option. All the computers are running Java. I can't see their LAN world but they can see mine. If I try xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx(Example IP)("Hosted at ...) at Direct Connect it says 'Connection refused'. We're on the same network and have the same IP. Tried putting my firewall on my computer off but I still couldn't connect.

**Important edit: Using Minecraft 1.8.9 or any earlier version that supports LAN worlds, the LAN world is recognized. But when I use Minecraft 1.9 it isn't. Could the problem be the Minecraft version?**

Comment: When you say 'lan world' do you mean it's a single player game that they share via the 'open to LAN' option?  Are you all running the Java computer edition?  What error do you encounter when trying to join their game (an actual error message, or just not able to find their game?)?

Comment: Does using the **Direct Connect** option work?

Comment: Which firewall did you turn off? Your computer's, or your router's? What setting is it currently at? What do you mean by "didn't work"? Do you mean that you weren't able to change the settings or that you were unable to connect after disabling the firewall?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/79252/118772

Comment: Important edit added with extra info!!

Comment: @iVictory For the fixed part in your question, please post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I also have when trying to play LAN with a mac and a windows 10 computer. When the mac hosts, everything works out wonderfully. When the windows 10 pc hosts, the mac can't find the LAN world. Here's my solution.

First, host the LAN server on the windows 10 computer. There should be a port given in the chat. Remember it. Then left click on the network icon in the lower right corner of the screen, and press "Network settings". On the screen that pops up, press "Advanced options". Scroll down through the properties until you get to the IPv4 address. There should be four numbers separated by periods, similar to this: 192.189.54.78. Remember them.

Now open up your Mac's minecraft. Go to multiplayer, then direct connect. Fill in the address with the IP first, then the port, like this: 192.168.54.78:56234

Then press Join Server, and you're good to go!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend

- Checking if you're connected to the internet
- Checking if the other player is connected to the internet
- Check if the LAN isn't blocked
- Contact Mojang if nothing works

Comment: local doesn't require internet.  It's better to check if either computer can ping the other first to confirm network connectivity between the two.