# Issue joining server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I attempted to join my brothers local mc server I have the IPv4 Address and the numbers but it always says can't connect to server It works in our house but in our other house it doesn't work. We are using mods if that affects anything (We used mods before and it worked perfectly)

We're at a different house than what we're normally at to play together.

Comment: Try some of the things here https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working/80011#80011

Comment: The IP address that you use at your house vs. the one at this new house are probably different. Double check to make sure you've got the right one.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid too much techno-babble, I'll try and keep it as simple as I can.

Basically, an IP address is the same as a Street Address. More often than not, when you connect to a different network, your IP Address will change. How the server reacts to that, depends on the setup. It *sounds* like they have allowed a *specific* address, but whether that is an *internal* or *external* address is also applicable. (An *internal* IP is the address of your Laptop/PC *within* the local network, and an *external* IP is the address of your whole network, that is exposed to the internet.

You can identify what your IP is easily by following these steps:

- For an *internal* IP:

  1. Open a "Command Prompt" by right-clicking on the start menu, and choosing it from the pop-up menu, or by searching for it by typing "cmd" into the search.
  2. Once open, type "ipconfig", then press enter. A whole lot of info will appear, but you are looking for a line that says: `IPv4 Address.....`. This will show you *your* laptop's internal IP.
- For an *external* IP:

  1. Open your internet browser, and go to google, then type in "What's my IP". This should bring up a response with your external IP, which is the IP for your *external network*. Now, in the case of being on the *same* network as the server, this will be less useful, but if you are on *separate* networks, any device with that external IP will be allowed on the server, regardless of the *internal* IP.

Adding these IPs to the server list will then allow you to connect.

Comment: The internal IP method only works on Windows. To find your internal IP on a Linux machine (maybe also Mac?), open the terminal and run `ifconfig | grep -w inet`. Look for the number which starts with `192.168`.

Answer (score -1):

you have a different IP in the other house than the one at your house. Everything its going to be different so you will need to find out the IP at the new house. Depending on the device you are using, you can look at the network options in the settings.

Comment: Hey John, while this answer is a good start, you might want to give some more context on how the OP might discover the different IP addresses between houses.