# Can't Connect to LAN from Mac to Windows

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

If I start a LAN from my Mac, my son can connect to it but if he creates a LAN on his Windows machine I can't connect and the "Scanning for games.." message just stays there. Any ideas what we should do? Is it a firewall rule?

Comment: You might find a solution [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80011/202130)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: That feature is pretty unreliable from my experience. Try manually entering its IP address in the "direct connect" or "add server" menu.