# Minecraft 1.7.10 LAN randomly stops working, restarting does not fix

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have minecraft 1.7.10 running on my desktop and laptop on the same wired internet connection. As of 15 minutes ago everything was working fine, then weird stuff happened.

My laptop lost connection to the world hosted on my desktop. I tried everything in MANY other posts about common lan issues and nothing worked.

Here is what I know:

-Both are running the same version of minecraft and are physically connected to the same router via ethernet cable

-The connection worked fine for weeks, so it is unlikely there is AP isolation

-I can ping test is successful both ways after I allowed it in my laptops firewall

-Disabling the firewall on both computers does noting

-Direct connecting does nothing

-Enabling all 4 of the different java things in firewall on public and private does noting

-Both computers are on the same subnet (?) 198.168.1.XXXX

-Shutting off the laptop, computer, router and modem. Leaving them off for a full 30 seconds, then starting. Did nothing

Fixed! Read answers

Comment: Why did you not try restarting the router and changing your IP address?

Comment: It's very weird that you can ping one way, but not the other, because a ping is in itself already a two-way operation. Can you try both again now to make sure it wasn't a temporary disconnection?

Comment: Why are you using 1.7.10? Do you have the same problem with 1.12.2 and 18w06a? What about the specific server variants? You should be able to get the 1.7.10 server from the wiki, the 1.12.2 server from the official website and the 18w06a server from the blog post.

Comment: I have been working at this for an hour and a half. I want to specifically use 1.7.10 because of the mods I use. I am using a clean 1.7.10 to troubleshoot LAN problems.

Comment: I didnt restart router before posting because I knew there was a 70-30 of it not working

Comment: There's a chance the router won't come back up? That's probably your issue, then. The symptoms exhibited are not gaming specific, however, and so this question doesn't belong here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about network troubleshooting, not gaming.

Comment: Frank, you misread my comment. I meant that it would not fix the problem. If you read the edit, you would see I have since tried this. Also, where should I put this if it does not belong here? Not being able to connect to other LAN worlds is a problem many minecraft players have, I believe it is important for them to see a way to fix this network problem

Comment: Agreed, this seems like a networking issue - can you get a LAN game to work in another game (that you might have installed?)

Comment: Not a networking issue, both computers can ping each other, one's firewall was set to block ping request

Comment: You're making my point for me; it's a computer configuration issue.  Your firewall has no bearing on the game.  The only way this is a gaming issue if it happens only in Minecraft, and then only maybe.  Try some other games; if they work fine under the same conditions, then we might have something to work with.

Comment: What I just said proves that the firewalls on both computers and the router/modem are configured properly, I am unsure how you misread this. Beyond those possibilities, it could be a java thing or a minecraft thing. It is likely something to do with minecraft that a power-user would know how to fix. It is however perplexing how it was working, but suddenly stopped working

Comment: We have a rather large number of users that come here and tell us they can't connect in Minecraft.  Chances are very good it's not the game, but your configuration, especially if it worked before.  Either way, *we don't know your setup*.  We don't know what you have, how it's configured, nor should we.  How your network functions is outside the scope of Arqade.  Try another game.  If that one works fine, that gives us more information to work with.  If it exhibits the same symptoms, then you know the game isn't the problem.

Comment: Read it and weep. Re-installing fixed it, meaning it was probably a minecraft problem. Though your advice for troubleshooting with another game was good. I feel silly for trying so many complicated solutions before such a simple one. Let this post be a testament to others, that the most complicated solution is not always the best

Comment: You should have mentioned that you used modded Minecraft. But that also means that this is tech-support for modded Minecraft and therefore offtopic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's tech support for modded Minecraft.

Comment: The mods installed had nothing to do with the server randomly not working, otherwise reinstall should not have helped. If you are going to close this, close it as a dupe of "lan does not work -minecraft" then edit the solution post to include reinstall of minecraft
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working

Comment: I can no longer delete this post, and all meaningful information from this post has been moved to the relevant post. Please close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- Uninstall minecraft
- Delete the .minecraft folder in appdata/roaming
- Restart computer
- Use CCleaner to do basic clean and registry clean (I also backed up registry)
- Install minecraft