# Why can’t other people join my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have made a Minecraft server that I host through my PC. Whenever my friends try to join, they either get this error or it doesn't stop loading. I have everything set up right in my router: I’m hosting from my PC, I have the right 25565 port.

Here is how I set it up: I went into **Firewall>PortForwarding** then did this: [image: Firewall port forwarding]

Here is how I set up **Advanced>PortForwarding**: [image: Advanced port forwarding]
**SO I was hoping that when they entered that IP address, it would check to see if they were using TCP or UDP, then route them through that port and into my server. Instead, the loading never stops, or they get this error.** 
`Failed to connect to server
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: 
Connection timed out: no further information:`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJfpb.jpg)

I had one of my friends take a look at it, and he said it seemed fine.

**If there is something that I can try to do to fix it, please give me a detailed description on how to do it. I am awful at finding tutorials.**

Comment: [related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/79252/93824)

Comment: How do you set up your server? Do you just open it to LAN?

Answer (score 1):

I hope your IP address is static, not dynamic. If it's dynamic, just change it to static. Check [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) out and follow those steps. Also, try disabling your firewall; sometimes it still won't work even if you allowed specific ports through it.

Comment: why would it change

Comment: and, if I am giving people the IP address that is my computer, then I wouldn't need to make that static. Plus, if i can connect to it using my IP address, then technically shouldn't other people be able to if i am giving them the IP that i'm using?

Comment: @ConnorForman actually, hosting a Minecraft server using a dynamic IP address means other devices will not be able to find that server. Try transferring to static and see what happens.

Comment: wacky. I'll give it a try.