# Cant connect to LAN worlds but can connect to servers Minecraft 15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friends all have the same WiFi but cant connect to each others Minecraft LAN worlds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, once you've opened a singleplayer map to LAN, the game should show up for your friends at the bottom of the server list screen. If it does, it's a simple matter of double left-clicking and you're in. If not, you have to know the IP and port of the server.

For Windows:

1. Press Windows key, type '`cmd`' and press enter.
2. Type '`ipconfig`' and press enter.
3. Find the network adapter of your shared internet.
4. Read 'ipv4,' this is the IP your friends will use to connect to you.
5. Open your game to LAN and read the chat line it sends, this includes the port they will connect through.

Connect with '`ip:port`'

E.g. if my IP is 1.2.3.4 and my port is 25565, my friends would Direct Connect to '`1.2.3.4:25565`'

Comment: Thank you but turns out i already fixed it with alot of different options