# Minecraft LAN Multiplayer doesn't always work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play multiplayer Minecraft (java edition) with my brother a lot, but it doesn't always work, which is frustrating. Sometimes it shows up, and sometimes it doesn't.
I'm trying to find a solution for when the shared game doesn't show up on my brother's computer (and vice versa). We made sure to use different accounts, connect to the same wifi (we tried Ethernet as well), allowed Minecraft and Java through the firewall, and it still didn't show up. Then we tried direct connect, restarting the computers, restarting Minecraft, reconnecting to wifi, and turning off the firewall, and none of those worked either. I'm not sure what to try next, other than to wait for it to start working again. Any help or information about why it's doing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One other thing to note: when I run steam, I can stream on both computers, so they are at least detecting one another.

Comment: Hi Naenuhlae, you can edit your question to add the additional information :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: @pppery Yep, that seems to be the same problem as mine