# How to play on lan with friends on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so i've checked all the other questions similar to this and i tried them out and they didn't work (how to add minecraft as a firewall exception for instance) and i've searched the question up on youtube and stuff but that didn't work either

Comment: You;re going to need to add more information - explain how it didn't work. What is your set up, i.e. are you all sharing the same wifi or ethernet connections, or are you playing in different houses? Write out what you did try (settings you changed, etc) and even add links to the tutorials and videos you watched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)