# Error message when friends try to join my minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hosting

I made a minecraft server yesterday and my friends had no issue joining. My internet was out this morning and now they get an error saying io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatdsocketexception: host is down, any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: [This list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96502/243753) might help, but your error code isn't listed there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Answer (score 0):

Tell your friends to disable their firewall for a brief moment and see if they can join when their firewall is off, then turn firewall back on.