# Minecraft LAN not showing up after multiple attempts to fix it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to play with my sister. I have tried the same version, same WiFi and Ethernet cable, firewall changes, nothing works.
I hope someone has an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: Try having your sister host and you join, instead of you hosting and she joins.

Comment: Maybe try a direct connection, should you know the IP.

Comment: Switching roles didn't work either, and I've yet to try out Direct Connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open you'r world from 'open from lan', I suggest you use Minecraft server([link to page](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server))
If that doesn't work then I suggest you'r sister try both things.