# Fixing LAN play issues in Minecraft: Java Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

I've done everything as it says to set up LAN play, but the connection keeps either timing out or immediately saying "Disconnected" upon successful connection. I really do not know what to do at this point, as we both have tried everything to get it working.

- Both clients are on Java Edition version 1.12.2.
- <strike>Both clients are playing with the Nomifactory modpack enabled. The same installation .zip file was used in Prism Launcher on both computers.</strike> This also occurs on Vanilla 1.12.2.
- Both clients are on the same network.
- We've triple-checked that the internal IP address and port number are correct.
- Minecraft (all instances of the Java binary) are allowed in both firewalls.
- If the notebook tries to connect to the computer, it gets timed out, while if the computer connects to the notebook, it connects successfully but immediately disconnects afterwards.

We're absolutely stumped as to what could be causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: Are the computer and laptop both using the same login credentials or are they logging in with different Mojang/Microsoft accounts? Basically, is the same player account trying to log in twice to the same game? Without knowing details of the  network setup, PC settings, etc. this will be difficult to answer. @TimmyJim's link has a lot of good info.

Comment: The notebook (which my friend plays on, he has no account) is playing in offline mode. I don't know if that affects LAN play though, it just doesn't let you login into servers that require an account.

Comment: Does the output log show anything out of the ordinary, if you enable it from the launcher?