# How can I have multiple Minecraft installs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I keep two different versions of Minecraft installed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/how-do-i-keep-two-different-versions-of-minecraft-installed)

I'd like to have at least three different Minecraft installs - one Minecraft Vanilla, one FiniteWater modded, and one the latest snapshot (where everything is ran as a SMP server). Is there a utility or method to have the `.jar` files for each stored in different places, or some soft of install manager?

Currently I have .rar'ed .minecraft folders that get zipped and unzipped as I play different versions, but surely there's got to be a better way of doing this.

I'm on Windows 7.