# Minecraft extra folders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Once I click to run minecraft a small window appears saying "Downloading runtime", then three other folders appear onto my desktop: Game, Native Log, and Runtime. This really annoys me, as I have to keep deleting them after I am done with a session of minecraft. Why is this? It never use to happen before.

Comment: which installer are you using?

Comment: Also, is your environment variables (for base folder) set to `.minecraft` and not some other place like your desktop? (Launchers such as [MultiMC](https://multimc.org) allows you do that)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you are running Minecraft.exe directly from your Desktop. The desktop is generally not a good place for executable files, and you shouldn't do that.

To fix your issue, you will have to move your Minecraft.exe somewhere else. I suggest you either move it to `%appdata%\.minecraft`, where the rest of the Minecraft files are stored. Or create a new folder somewhere, such as `C:\Games\Minecraft` and move it there.

Afterwards, create a shortcut to the exe on your desktop, e.g. by doing *Right-Click > Send to > Desktop*, or Right-Click dragging the icon and selecting *Create Shortcut*

Comment: Your folder path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You want the older version, they now include the runtime and a few other things. The version you want is the older version which requires Java installed already.

You can get it from here: https://beta.minecraft.net/en/download/

**Please note this may change, but I've attached a screenshot to highlight as I had issues finding it since I only glanced for a few minutes.**

[image: Screenshot of the beta download page.]

Answer (score -1):

You can create a bat or sh file that will have the program run into a different directory:
[Second Reply.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100106/is-it-possible-to-use-a-different-folder-than-minecraft)

If you don't want to do that, you can symlink the directories.

For me, I had a similar problem with my computer. You can either move the minecraft executable to the

> %appdata%.minecraft

folder.

(Check where your Java path is leading to, it shouldn't be heading to your desktop)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, create a folder in C:/!Games and then put in there minecraft. Then right click to create a shortcut which you can use on your desktop. Also if you are bothered by a messy desktop trying using the program fences. It comes with a quick hide tool and other desktop organizing features.