# How can I run Minecraft 1.6.4 on 1.7.2 client?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I play older versions of Minecraft?

I want to play 1.6.4, but my current installed version is 1.7.2

Comment: Hi Helen, it's possible that this question already answers your question: [How do I downgrade Minecraft to play on a server running an older version?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19426/how-do-i-downgrade-minecraft-to-play-on-a-server-running-an-older-version), if not, can you explain more what the problem is?