# Minecraft versions gone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for years now, however I ran into a problem I haven't before: when I opened Minecraft I only had version 1.16.2 and a couple of modded versions. I remember adding some vanilla versions but I just assumed it was nothing.

I went to installation to get a new 1.8.9 (I wanted to test some old worlds), went to versions and there was only version 1.16.2 and a couple of modded versions. I went to make sure that snapshot and historical boxes were checked and they were, I closed the browser down and opened it again still happened.

I went in the `.minecraft` folder, saved all the important stuff, uninstalled the game and installed it again but now I can only go on Minecraft 1.16.2.

To fix this I cant get the other versions simply cause it wont let me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I downgrade Minecraft to play on a server running an older version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19426/how-do-i-downgrade-minecraft-to-play-on-a-server-running-an-older-version) (Note: if this question/answer is out of date, it should be updated, not have a duplicate created).

Comment: The reason it might not let you is check that the Windows Ransomware Protection is not getting in the way of where you are trying to save it, if it is in the default location in .minecraft it should be fine but check for that